# Cannot make LCD & Gyro work together

Tags: arduino-mega, lcd, mpu6050

I'm new to this so there are some poor methods in my code when I try to introduce the LCD into the loop. My issue is that the LCD delay and the servo delay are interfering with each other. How can I isolate them? I like the 50ms response for the servo. But I would like maybe a 200ms refresh for the LCD. But in their current state they are giving a very odd response if I have them both in the loop. The servo is spinning slower as though it's adding both delays. If I disable the LCD it all goes back to normal. Any ideas? Could someone please show me the correct method so I can expand in the future? Thanks!!!!

I've got this so far:

```
#include<Wire.h>
const int MPU_addr=0x68;  // I2C address of the MPU-6050
int16_t AcX,AcY,AcZ,Tmp,GyX,GyY,GyZ;

//SERVO
#include <Servo.h>
Servo microservo1;
int servo_pin = 8;

//MAPPED VALUES
int16_t AcXmapped, AcYmapped, AcZmapped;

//LCD
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
const int rs = 12, en = 11, d4 = 5, d5 = 4, d6 = 3, d7 = 2;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);
//initializes the library

void setup(){

  //SERVO SETUP
  microservo1.attach ( servo_pin );

  //WIRE SETUP
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire.write(0x6B);  // PWR_MGMT_1 register
  Wire.write(0);     // set to zero (wakes up the MPU-6050)
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Transmission Line Initializing"); 
  delay(350);
  //print("3"); print("2"); print("1");
  Serial.println("3");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("2");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("1");
  delay(1000);

  //LCD SETUP
  lcd.begin(16,2); //setup LCD number of columns and rows
  digitalWrite(9,1); //can either go 0 --> 1 or LOW --> HIGH || turns LCD on or off ||
  analogWrite(6,70); //contrast setting for the text on the LCD
}

void loop(){

  //WIRE LOOP
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr); 
  Wire.write(0x3B);  // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(MPU_addr,14,true);  // request a total of 14 registers
  AcX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) & 0x3C (ACCEL_XOUT_L)    
  AcY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3D (ACCEL_YOUT_H) & 0x3E (ACCEL_YOUT_L)
  AcZ=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3F (ACCEL_ZOUT_H) & 0x40 (ACCEL_ZOUT_L)
  Tmp=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x41 (TEMP_OUT_H) & 0x42 (TEMP_OUT_L)
  GyX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x43 (GYRO_XOUT_H) & 0x44 (GYRO_XOUT_L)
  GyY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x45 (GYRO_YOUT_H) & 0x46 (GYRO_YOUT_L)
  GyZ=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x47 (GYRO_ZOUT_H) & 0x48 (GYRO_ZOUT_L)
  Serial.print(" | AcX = "); Serial.print(AcX);
  Serial.print(" | AcY = "); Serial.print(AcY);
  Serial.print(" | AcZ = "); Serial.print(AcZ);
  //Serial.print(" | Tmp =  "); Serial.print(Tmp/340.00+36.53);  //equation for temperature in degrees C from datasheet
  Serial.print(" | GyX = "); Serial.print(GyX);
  Serial.print(" | GyY = "); Serial.print(GyY);
  Serial.print(" | GyZ = "); Serial.println(GyZ);

  //MAPPING the values from e.g. AcX to AcXmapped so they're better values for servo control.
  //set the AcX inside the map to negative if you want to invert the rotation of the servo.
  AcXmapped = map (AcX, -17000, 17000, 0, 180); //ROLL
  AcYmapped = map (AcY, -17000, 17000, 0, 180); //PITCH
  AcZmapped = map (AcZ, -17000, 17000, 0, 180); //YAW

  //SERVO LOOP
  microservo1.write(AcYmapped);
  //50 ms response between movements
  delay(50); 

  //LCD LOOP
  lcd.setCursor(0,0); //set the cursor to (0,0)
  lcd.print(AcYmapped);
  delay(50);

  //EXTRA LCD
  lcd.noAutoscroll(); //turns off autoscroll
  lcd.clear(); //clears the screen for the next loop


}
```

Answer (score 1):

First upload the msg errors you've get .
Second the lcd can't display values in realtime because when the gyroscope move the arduino blocking the lcd and reading the data from gyroscope because you using no scheduling coding. 
I recommend you to use millis  instead of delays and use  multitasking code like freertos .

Comment: I fixed the error message BUT (bracket issue) my code is still giving me trouble. My delays are combining between the servo and the LCD. Do you know how I can isolate them so that I can give them both their own delay?

Comment: Use millis() if you think realtime data is necessary  . I noticed that you use lcd.noautoscroll() function under the extra lcd comment which is not necessary because the lcd by default doesn't scroll the characters. So try to delete that function . Now first try to delete all the delay and run your code then watch how the system behaves . Actually the servo take it's own time when it moves . During the movement of servo the arduino blocks every thing until the servo reach the desire angle then execute the rest in the loop .

Comment: the servo in this question is a hobby servo .... it is non-blocking because there is no position feedback ..... the code simply changes the PWM signal that is being sent to the servo ... the servo does the motion to the desired angle automatically

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `delay()` at all. You need to refactor your code to record the value of `millis()` at the beginning of a time interval and then wait until the new value of `millis()` is greater by the desired interval. Do a google search on "Arduino blink without delay" for articles that discuss this coding technique. It's a fundamental of programming for a single-threaded microcontroller like the Arduino, and something you must learn to do if you're going to write anything of any complexity for the platform.